# how to spy/stub a function and stub an action Vuex in the component vue3 composition api

Tags: vuejs3, cypress, vuex, vue-test-utils

my stack:

1. cypress
2. @vue/test-utils
3. component in vue3 in composition api (<script setup />)

My test, i would like to spy a method inside a component, and spy action vuex inside a method in component.

myComponent

```
testView.vue

<template>
    <div class="test" @click="a()">test </test>
<template>
    <script setup>
    function a() {
        // logic 
        b()
    }
    function b() {
        // logic
        // launch dispatch in simple action in vuex
        dispatch('actionA')
    }
</script>


test.cy.js
describe('ClientView.vue', () => {
    it('test', async () => {
        const store = createStore({
            state() {
                return {
                    varA: null,
                }
            },
            actions: {
                actionA(context, newMessage) {
                    return Promise.resolve()
                },
            },
        })
        const mockRoute = createRouter({ history: createWebHistory(), routes: [] })
        mockRoute.currentRoute.value.name = 'testUrl'
        mockRoute.currentRoute.value.params = undefined
        const wrapper = mount(testView, {
            global: {
                mocks: {
                    $route: mockRoute,
                },
                plugins: [store, mockRoute]
            },
        })
        const spyA = cy.spy(wrapper.vm, 'a').as('a')
        const spyB = cy.spy(wrapper.vm, 'b').as('bSpy')
       

          // simulate click and launch function a()
          // I see in my log, the function A, b  and the action is called
         wrapper.find('test').trigger('click')
        expect(spyA ).to.be.called
        expect(spyB ).to.be.called
        expect(stubB ).to.be.called
       
    })
})
```

My errors

spyA is called ok

```
expected  spyB to have been called at least once, but it was never called
expected stubB to have been called at least once, but it was never called
```

My declaration of my spy and stub for b is not correct ?  i don't understand why.

// If a modify my template

```
testView.vue

<template>
    <div class="test" @click="a()">test </test>
<template>
    <script setup>
    function a() {
        // logic 
        this.b()
    }
    function b() {
        // logic
        // launch dispatch in simple action in vuex
        dispatch('actionA')
    }
</script>
```

My test work ... but ... if i run my frontend 'this' is not autorize.

Error frontend

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'b')
```

Cypress has a problem with the version of vue3 in composition api ?

Comment: I don't think `wrapper.vm` provides access to internal functions. Do you see it when inspecting?

Comment: i close this ticket , i see the problem and i will recreate a new question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The spy code is correct and should work after `// simulate click and launch function a()`, so as mentioned it's likely the vm does not hold a reference to the functions.

You can easily check if that's so with `console.log(wrapper.vm.a)`, it should not be `undefined` for your spy to work.

If it is `undefined`, you could spy on the internal functions by exposing them on the `window` object.

Something like this:

```js
// component
if (window.Cypress) {
  window.a = a
}

...

// test
const spyA = cy.spy(window, 'a').as('a')
```

Comment: i close this ticket , i see the problem and i will recreate a new question